# Find distance between two DIVs using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two DIVs that I need to know the calculated browser distance (in height) of them.
I have read about the offset feature but the examples were not written for the way I am trying to do this.

Example usage:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

I want to know the distance between these two.

Please help me to find the distance dynamically with jQuery.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.foo').offset().top - $('.bar').offset().top
```

As long as each class only has one element on the page.
If they are not unique, give the two elements an ID and reference with that.

Comment: Didn't work but then looked under your code and that was the reason! two occurrences of one of the DIVs.

In the end, I had to use another method.

Comment: It doesn't include border size in coordinates

Answer (score 12):

Use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$('.foo').offset().top - $('.bar').offset().top
```

Comment: Your example uses `.offset.top`.  It should be `.offset().top`.

Answer (score 0):

This function finds the distance in pixels between the centre of two elements, no jquery:

```
function distanceBetweenElems(elem1, elem2) {
    var e1Rect = elem1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var e2Rect = elem2.getBoundingClientRect();
    var dx = (e1Rect.left+(e1Rect.right-e1Rect.left)/2) - (e2Rect.left+(e2Rect.right-e2Rect.left)/2);
    var dy = (e1Rect.top+(e1Rect.bottom-e1Rect.top)/2) - (e2Rect.top+(e2Rect.bottom-e2Rect.top)/2);
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return dist;
}
```

I use it like this:

```
var target1 = document.querySelector('#foo');
var target2 = document.querySelector('#bar');
if (distanceBetweenElems(target1,target2)<100){
     target1.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: Just a note - `(e1Rect.left+(e1Rect.right-e1Rect.left)/2)` can be simplified to `(e1Rect.left + e1Rect.right) / 2` - after all, the centre is just the average of the left and right edges.