# jQuery find which parent is closer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery you can call `closest` to find the closest parent.

If I have a `a` in a `li` in a `ul` in a `td` in a `table`. I want to find out if the `ul` parent is closer than the `table` parent. Obviously in this case the answer is obvious.

If I run `$('a').closest('table').length` or `$('a').closest('ul').length` both return 1.

I would like to find out which parent is closer in the DOM.

Technically if there were a method than in this case `$('a').closer('ul', 'table')` would return the `ul` because it is closer in the DOM.

```
<table> <!-- Is this closer -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul> <!-- Or is this closer -->
                <li>
                    <a href="#">A button</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you should post a snippet of the HTML that you are referring to. It will make things clearer to everyone.

Comment: 1. As bob has mentioned, HTML is needed to determine position and relation of the elements/nodes within the DOM. 2. All elements (except the root which is `<html>` has only **one** parent. How can an element have more than one parent? What you mean is ancestors.

Comment: @zer00ne: It's jQuery's fault: the function to get all ancestors is called `.parents()`.

Comment: @Amadan I guess `.ancestors()` would be too verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list multiple element selectors to the `closest` function, it will only find the closest of one of them:

```
$('a').closest('table, ul')
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).on("click", function( event ) {
  $(event.target).closest("li, b").toggleClass("hilight");
});
```

```css
.hilight{
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><b>Click me!</b></li>
  <li>You can also click this line <b>or click me!</b></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And then you'll also want $(elem).get(0).tagName to know what you've actually found.

Answer (score 3):

**Use** [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/). **It returns a list of all parents that are ordered from closest to farthest.**

The difference between using this and using `.closest(selector)` is that it accepts a jQuery object instead of a selector string, which has to be hard coded. Meanwhile jQuery objects can be collections and so can be generated on the fly.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.getClosest = function(testElements) {
    var element = $(this);
    var parents = element.parents();
    var indexClosest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    testElements.each(function() {
      var index = parents.index($(this));
      if (index > -1 && index < indexClosest)
        indexClosest = index;
    });
    return parents.eq(indexClosest);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Use the function like this:

```
$("a").getClosest($("table, ul"))
```

[Fiddle with advanced use case](https://jsfiddle.net/6f3964bn/4/)

Comment: I actually tried to use `.index()` and it didn't work for me. I would be interested if you made a working snippet of this.

Comment: The benefit of my solution is that you can pass it a multitude of jQuery objects instead of a multitude of selector strings. Selector strings would have to be hard coded or generated using some other method, while jQuery objects are easily obtainable programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I like Fabian's answer; but to actually measure the distance, you can use this:

```js
var $parentsUntilTable = $('li').parentsUntil('table');
var $parentsUntilUl = $('li').parentsUntil('ul');
console.log($parentsUntilTable.length < $parentsUntilUl.length
           ? 'table is closer'
           : 'ul is closer');
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of the `.closer()` method that returns the selector that is closest to the given element:

```
$.fn.closer = function(varargs) {
  var $elem = $(this);
  while ($elem.length) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
      if ($elem.is(arguments[i])) {
        return arguments[i];
      }
    }
    $elem = $elem.parent();
  }
  return null;
};
```

See it in action [on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkv6ofos/).

Answer (score -1):

An element only has one parent node, above those are ancestor nodes.

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149590/1876047 - you can use

```
$(elem1).offset().top - $(elem2).offset.().top
```

As both nodes are ancestors of the element you are considering, the one furthest from the root of the DOM tree is the closet to your element.

So if the above difference is greater than 0, then elem2 is closest, otherwise elem1 is closest.

Comment: This measures layout distance, not tree distance - completely different question.