# jQuery find closest of the given classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to find the `.closest()` ancestor with any one of the given class.

```
jQuery("#gid").closest(".ui-tabs,.tab-pane,.jomsTabsContent");
```

What I want here, is which ever of the given classes is the closest one, I need to select that.

So for the following eg.

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
 <div class="bar">
  <div class="monkey">
    <div id="gid">
    <div>
  <div>
 <div>
<div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery("#gid").closest(".foo,.bar,.monkey");
```

I want the above to select (only) the `.monkey` div.

PS: *I know the above isn't correct syntax for what I'm 'looking for', but I am demonstrating what I am looking for.*

Comment: That's exactly the way to do it.

Comment: Yup Indeed, It looks like I was right after all :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps... It looks like, If there is an overlapping hirerchy, then then `.closest()` returns the closest of the provided CSS group.

Got it after a little google-foo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834010/jquery-find-which-parent-is-closer/35834065).